# Samsung 970 EVO has password I never made?

Tags: linux, ssd, storage, nvme

I used the "Secure Wipe SSD" tool in the UEFI of my ASROCK A320M-DGS motherboard on my Samsung 970 EVO and now whenever I boot my PC, it asks for a password that I never set?!

Is there any way to remove this password without knowing it, bear in mind I have no need for the data on this drive so if this involves wiping it in some way then that's fine.

The drive is visible when I run `lsblk` (on Linux Mint 19).

I have already tried a couple of things which have failed and will hopefully give you more insight into the problem:

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1:
HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

---

```
$ sudo nvme format /dev/nvme0n1
NVME Admin command error:INVALID_OPCODE(1)
```

Any ideas of what's happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried retracing steps with the Secure Wipe SSD tool, and seeing if you can intentionally set a password?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I tried re-wiping it but since it now has a 'password' it won't let me :/

Comment: For the next time, you can do this without bios following those instructions: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase (not that it can help with a locked drive without knowing the password...)

Answer (score 1):

You should check your SSD documentation or contact the vendor - there is likely an utility to fix your drive.

Typically SED (Self Encrypting) drives always encrypt the data whenever you want it or not, and the key is left unprotected if you didn't set a password. Therefore the "Secure Erase" function do not actually erase anything on the drive, instead it wipes the encryption key so the on-disk data is no longer decipherable.

I guess in your case by asking to secure erase the drive, it wiped the key in a way that made the drive think it's merely encrypted. If you can tell the drive to drop the password it should regenerate a new unprotected key and return to its original state with all data wiped.